# ActionScript3: How to make an animation out of a series of images?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, image-processing

I'm new to AS3 and I'm trying to create a simple game with it.
So far, I have been able to draw images like this:

```
[Embed(source = 'C:/mypath/myimage.png')]
public static var myImageClass:Class;
private var myImage:Bitmap = new myImageClass();
```

and then render myImage.
but that draws only a picture with no animation.
What I want is to import this picture:

[image]

and then cut the image to series of subimages and draw an animation out of them, rather than a single image. How may I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "*Blitting*".  You could accomplish it with fairly decent results, depending on your deployment target and how many animations you require, using [BitmapData.copyPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29), but it's more ideal to use the [Starling Framework](http://gamua.com/starling/), which employs [Stage3D](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html) hardware acceleration.

More here:

- [Introducing the Starling Framework](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=147) (Video tutorial)
- [Starling documentation](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `SpriteSheet` support. You can easily write this yourself or use existing libraries (like [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) for instance).

The idea is to draw an area of the image at each frame to actually create the animation. Depending on the format of your sprite sheet, you may have to add another file to describe the positions of each rectangle to draw.

[This page](http://blog.flexwiz.net/spritesheet-animation-in-as3/) explains how to implement it.